# Standard height refrigerator outlet

Tags: electrical, receptacle

What is the standard height for a refrigerator outlet? 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Where are you on this planet?

Comment: What do you plan to use the outlet for besides the fridge? Will it be a GFCI-receptacle combo device and you will need to reset it from time to time?

Answer (score 4):

36” allows you to plug it in and keeps the cord off the floor so you don’t push the refrigerator on top of the cord when you push it back.

Answer (score 3):

There is no "standard height". The National Electrical Code never lists a height requirement.

Tradition has the height for most floor line receptacles about 12" to the bottom of the box.

The Americans with Disabilities Act recommends receptacles no lower than 19" to center of receptacle.

Normally, contractors and installers choose a height and stick with it for receptacles, switches, bathroom receptacles, and thermostats. It is more convention or tradition than anything else.

This is truly an area where you get to decide as long as it is 48" or below, it can serve the floor line.

Good luck!